# How to access object property names

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a data structure like this:

```
var r =  
{ 
 "abc": ["a1","a2","a3"] ,
 "xyz": ["x1","x2","x3"] 
}
```

I am accessing these elements like this

```
jQuery.each(r,function(index,ele){ 
      alert(ele);    // values like a1,a2,a3 in ele -loop
});
```

I am getting values **a1, a2, a3** in elements in **ele** variable.

I want to access values **abc** and **xyz**.

how to access value **abc** in loop?

fiddle: [fiddle]: http://jsfiddle.net/ce58qutw/

Comment: That isn't JSON. It is just an object.

Comment: Using `each` over an object the `index` and `ele` arguments are key and value, respectively. Now you alert the value under `ele` argument, but you want the key, which is under `index`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
jQuery.each(r,function(index,ele){ 
   alert(index);   
});
```

---

Keep in mind that the first parameter to the call back function is key and the second one is the value.

And the proper code would be,

```
jQuery.each(r,function(key,val){ 
   alert(key);   
});
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ce58qutw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `for..in` loop:

```
for (var key in r) {
    alert(key);
};
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/ce58qutw/1/)

Answer (score 0):

[..Demo..](http://jsfiddle.net/ce58qutw/3/)try this,

```
$.each(r,function(index,ele){ 
    if(index==="abc"){
    for(i=0;i<ele.length;i++){   alert(ele[i]);    }
   }
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it using vanilla JS very easily:

```
Object.keys(r).forEach(function (key) {
  alert(key);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, result will be an object and it looks like a dictionary to me having key value pairs.

You could do something like this

```
$.each(value, function (key, value) {
alert(key) // that's your key value    
this['prop_name'];  // iterate over your value object
});
```